# How does _bindingMap get populated?

Tags: mvvmcross

In MvxViewContainer there is a _bindingMap which is used to map ViewModels to Views so that "FirstViewModel" gets mapped to "FirstView". For my version of MvvmCross for Mac, I'd like to make the mapping "FirstViewController" instead. Indeed, somehow it knows when "FirstView" is a MvxViewController to do the right thing. How does this work?

```
public virtual IMvxMacView CreateView(MvxViewModelRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        CurrentRequest = request;
        var viewType = GetViewType(request.ViewModelType);
```

I'm asking for the current version (v3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the wiki](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup), using `[MvxViewFor(typeof(YourViewModel))]` is probably the easiest solution:

### Overriding View-ViewModel associations

By default, MvvmCross discovers the ViewModel that a View is associated with using the type of ViewModel discovered by name convention

This makes prototyping initial application generally very functionality straight-forward.

However, as applications grow in size and complexity, then sometimes developers like to override this lookup behaviour.

To do this they can instead:

- provide a concrete type of the ViewModel where one is specified - e.g. as:

  ```
      public new DetailViewModel ViewModel
          {
               get { return base.ViewModel as DetailViewModel; }
               set { base.ViewModel = value; }
          }
  ```
- or provide an explicit type of the ViewModel specified using an `MvxViewForAttribute`

Further, in cases where every microsecond of startup time is essential, they can also help reduce the Reflection overhead by overriding the `InitializeViewLookup` method - e.g.

```
    protected override void InitializeViewLookup()
    {
        var viewModelViewLookup = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
        {
            { typeof (FirstViewModel), typeof(FirstView) },
            { typeof (SecondViewModel), typeof(SecondView) },
            //
            { typeof (UmpteenthViewModel), typeof(UmpteenthView) },
        };

        var container = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewsContainer>();
        container.AddAll(viewModelViewLookup);
    }
```